# Single Process Worker or Something More DB Specific?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, oracle

I need to avoid overlapping date ranges in my database.  I would like this to be database agnostic -- it's a hard enough problem even w/ it not being database angostic (http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:474221407101).  I have only one application writing to the database.  A few others are reading from it, where read performance is critical.  The application that does the writing is threaded -- it's a web app -- and is in a cluster.

So, I was thinking it may be easiest to just ensure that only 1 process was writing at a time.  Is this the right approach?  If so, should I just have a single threaded app that listens to some request queue and processes these requests in the order that it receives them?  I have all of these requests in a database anyway and was just thinking of using the created_at date and status to process them.

Comment: my first thought would be write a trigger that fires on any DML and enforces your business rule.  Would probably work for Oracle, not sure about mySql.  Every db is different and has different features/functionality, so good luck with the one size fits all approach.

Answer (score 0):

One way to address this is to setup a table which contains all the days as `DATE` values. Soemthing like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEDULER (
    SCHEDULED_DATE DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    OWNER_ID NUMBER(8)
);
```

`SCHEDULED_DATE` would represent one day and would be stored with the time at `00:00`. Primary Key integrity will ensure that no two records can be inserted with the same `SCHEDULED_DATE`. The `OWNER_ID` is the reference to who "owns" that date. Given that `DATE` variables are 7 bytes in Oracle, and the number isn't too large (max 22 bytes) you shouldn't have trouble with storage. 100 years worth of dates would only be about 10 MB!